# How do I sync two Google Calendar accounts?

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business

I'm using Google Calendar extensively for personal needs. I share my availability publicly so other people could schedule events with me. Now I have work email under G Suite. As far as I know G Suite admins can potentially see all events in my calendar including details.

I want:

- to have my personal calendar, where only I can see events details
- to allow other people see my availability, that excludes my personal events as well as work events
- to allow other people see my availability whether they are inviting me by my personal email or work email